# How to map the extent of MapView on to opengles view extent

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, augmented-reality

I have displayed a map using mapfragment and i have drawn a opengles line . Augmenting these two views i want the road line that i have drawn on opengles (using latlngs and convertion to opengles extent values) to exactly match with the roadway on map.How can i do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Create a view that draws the map, crate a subview to that map view which can be transparent and you can see the map in the background.
- Create a system which describes the path that you want to draw with openGL. For instance a line would consist of two 2D points each containing a latitude and a longitude.
- Make a system to draw those coordinates as a path with the openGL.
- Create a "refresh" method which will redraw the openGL content (the paths). What you need to do is give the openGL view the current visible coordinate system as a top-left corner and bottom right corner in latitude and longitude. Use these 2 points to define the `glOrtho`, `left = top_left.latitude`, `right = bottom_right.latitude`... This will define your coordinate system to be the same as with the map coordinates. So using this no transition to view coordinates are needed at all. Now simply redraw the openGL view with new data (coordinate system and the path).
- Call the refresh method whenever the map has changed, scrolled, path changed...

Comment: i have drawn the line opengles by converting the latlng values to cartesian coords using a formula like this: x = R * cos(lat) * cos(lon)
y = R * cos(lat) * sin(lon)
z = R *sin(lat)

Comment: Thanks alot for ur response. i still want some clarification. i have drawn the line opengles by converting the latlng values to cartesian coords using a formula like this: x = R * cos(lat) * cos(lon)
y = R * cos(lat) * sin(lon)
z = R *sin(lat) . this gives the points with respect to sphere so the values will be in multiples of 1000. i have done transformation to it by taking a current location cartesian value and drawn the line whose coordinates now will be in range of (1,1)(-1,-1).. is this the way to transform it ?

Comment: No, you do not need that. Unless you are zooming out to such a distance you can actually see map "curvy" you do not need to transform to cartesian coords at all. You can simply treat the latitude and longitude as cartesian. You simply set the GL coordinate system to be the same as your map. As I said, use orthographical matrix and insert the map border coordinates.

Comment: can you please provide me some reference links to do so.

Comment: to draw in opengles in using vertex (x,y,z) and passing to vertex buffer with color . how can i directly pass latlng to this vertex buffer?

Comment: Here map border coordinates are changes as i zoom in and out.But the opengl line which is before visible cannot be seen now. This is because of given glorthof with latlng. how to resolve this? how to pass values to vertex buffer with latlng

Comment: You just pass the latitude and longitude as x and y.

Answer (score 0):

Yes performed the steps as mentioned above.But the line is not drawn on opengles surface with the latlngs that i have passed as vertices to the vertex buffer.